# Packages not found despite correct /etc/apt/source.list

Tags: 12.10, apt, software-sources

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like this

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

`apt-get update` is just fine. `apt-get clean` has no output and `apt-get -f install` does not install any packages. Nevertheless packages like `xfce4` or `emacs` cannot be found.

The output `apt-get update`

```
    Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease
    Treffer http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease
    Treffer http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports InRelease
    Treffer http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources
    Treffer http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted i386 Packages
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe i386 Packages
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse i386 Packages
    Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-de_DE
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-de
    Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-de
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
    Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-de
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-de
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-de
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main i386 Packages
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe i386 Packages
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main i386 Packages
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted i386 Packages
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe i386 Packages
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main i386 Packages
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted i386 Packages
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe i386 Packages
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en
    Treffer http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-de_DE
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-de_DE
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-de_DE
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-de_DE
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-de_DE
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-de
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-de_DE
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-de
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-de_DE
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-de
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-de_DE
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-de
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-de_DE
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-de
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-de_DE
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-de
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-de_DE
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-de
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-de_DE
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-de
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-de_DE
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-de
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-de_DE
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-de
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-de_DE
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-de
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-de_DE
    Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-de
    Paketlisten werden gelesen...
```

Unfortunatly its in german Treffer means something like Hit and Ign could mean ignore?

```
apt-cache policy emacs
N: Paket emacs kann nicht gefunden werden
```

Which means that the package could not be found.

```
sudo apt-get install emacs23
[sudo] password for joachim: 
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen... Fertig
Paket emacs23 ist nicht verfügbar, wird aber von einem anderen Paket
referenziert. Das kann heißen, dass das Paket fehlt, dass es abgelöst
wurde oder nur aus einer anderen Quelle verfügbar ist.
```

E: Paket »emacs23« hat keinen Installationskandidaten

The error messages means that the package emacs23 is not available but is referenced by another package. This could mean that the package is missing or that it has been terminated or that is available from another source.

```
sudo apt-get install emacs
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen... Fertig
E: Paket emacs kann nicht gefunden werden
```

The error means that the package emacs could not be found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the file really called `/etc/apt/source.list`? The name should be `sources.list`. What is the output of `apt-get update`?

Comment: its `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I edited that.

Comment: *"`apt-get -f install` does not install any packages"* This only needs to run if you have broken dependencies... What does the output of `apt-cache policy emacs` say for example? And what is the output of `sudo apt-get install emacs`?

Comment: Ok, this looks fine. What's the output of `apt-get install emacs`? What about `apt-get install emacs23`? And `apt-cache policy emacs emacs23`? Do you have a file `/etc/apt/preferences` or files in `/etc/apt/preferences.d`?

Comment: Seems to me that is has nothing to do with sources.list because I tryed a perfectly new one generated with this http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Comment: @joachim I have no clue as to why your package management can't locate the package. Did you change something about `/var` mount points or other things out of the ordinary? And please provide the output of `apt-cache dumpavail | grep ^Package | wc -l`.